# Getting error IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to read text from sObj.txt & write in MPadd.txt with some prefix text. The sObj.txt contains a vertical strip of words (1 in each line) & the number of lines in this file are variable (determined by user). Here is the script that I am using:

```
Dim commands() =
    {
        "stmotd -a {0}",
        "stmotd -b 15 {0}"
    }


Dim counter As Integer = 1
Dim objLines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\temp\sObj.txt")

Using SW As New IO.StreamWriter("c:\temp\MPadd.txt", True)
    For Each line in objLines
        SW.WriteLine(string.Format(commands(counter), line))
        counter += 1
    Next
End Using
```

But when executed it returns error "IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled" also says Index was outside the bounds of the array. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays in .NET are zero-based.

Use

```
Dim counter As Integer = 0
```

And obviously, `objLines` may contain no more than two lines.

Maybe you meant to emit all `commands` for each line?

```
For Each line in objLines
    For Each cmd in commands
        SW.WriteLine(string.Format(cmd, line))
    Next
Next
```

EDIT:

```
Dim joined_lines = File.ReadAllText("C:\temp\sObj.txt").Replace(vbNewLine, " ")

Using SW As New IO.StreamWriter("c:\temp\MPadd.txt", True)
    For Each cmd In commands
        SW.WriteLine(String.Format(cmd, joined_lines))
    Next
End Using
```

Comment: your code works but the output is 
stmotd -a WINFPH
stmotd -b 15 WINFPH
stmotd -a WINMAC
stmotd -b 15 WINMAC
stmotd -a WINPPC
stmotd -b 15 WINPPC
stmotd -a WINVPN
stmotd -b 15 WINVPN

where WINxxx are the text from sObj.txt file. 

However I need the output like this :

stmotd -a WINFPH WINMAC WINPPC WINVPN
stmotd -b 15 WINFPH WINMAC WINPPC WINVPN

Can you please help ?

Answer (score 0):

As you only have two items in your commands array, if you import more than two lines from your file, then you'll increment `counter` more than twice, so you'll attempt to access an item in the array that doesn't exist, which means this line:

```
SW.WriteLine(string.Format(commands(counter), line))
```

will cause an `index out of range` error.  Arrays in .NET are also 0 based, so `counter` should start at 0, unless you mean to exclude the first item in the `objLines` array

**EDIT:** Yes to do what you've mentioned in your comment you need to change it to the following:

```
Using SW As New IO.StreamWriter("c:\temp\MPadd.txt", True)
    For Each cmd in commands
        Dim strLine As New String

        For Each line in objLines
            strLine += " WIN" + line
        Next

        SW.WriteLine(String.Format(cmd, strLine.ToUpper().Trim()))
    Next
End Using
```

This will append all items in your array to a single line with a WIN prefix:

```
stmotd -a WINFPH WINMAC WINPPC WINVPN 
stmotd -b 15 WINFPH WINMAC WINPPC WINVPN
```

Comment: Is there a way to print multiple entries from the file sObj.txt against the commands ? For example: stmotd -a WINFPH WINMAC WINPPC WINVPN stmotd -b 15 WINFPH WINMAC WINPPC WINVPN where WINxxx are the entries from sObj.txt

Answer (score 0):

the array "commands" has only 2 items in it. When the counter value is 2, it throws an exception. I am not sure of your requirement, but you could modify your code as follows:

```
Dim commands() =
    {
        "stmotd -a {0}",
        "stmotd -b 15 {0}"
    }


Dim counter As Integer = 0
Dim objLines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\temp\sObj.txt")
Using SW As New IO.StreamWriter("c:\temp\MPadd.txt", True)
      for Each line in objLines
      If counter > 1 Then
     counter = 0
      End If
      SW.WriteLine(string.Format(commands(counter), line))
      counter += 1
Next
End Using
```

If you are sure of the no. of items in the commands array, I would recommend you to hard code the item index rather than using a counter variable.

Comment: Is there a way to print multiple entries from the file sObj.txt against the commands ? For example:

stmotd -a WINFPH WINMAC WINPPC WINVPN 
stmotd -b 15 WINFPH WINMAC WINPPC WINVPN

where WINxxx are the entries from sObj.txt